# Dynamically update plugin view in ckeditor 5

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm using ckEditor 5.
My aim is to create a simple search functionality to perform some ajax calls, allow the user to select from a result list and act accordingly (inserting link, or image, or media...).

The problem is that I want to dynamically update the plugin view. Something similar to this: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/520, but I'm using a dropdown in the toolbar (I started from the EmbedMedia plugin and didn't care too much about design for now).
I asked the same question on their git (https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1681)

My template is like:

```js
        this.setTemplate( {
            tag: 'form',

            attributes: {
                class: [
                    'ck',
                    'ck-results-form'
                ],

                tabindex: '-1'
            },

            children: [
                this.searchInputView,
                this.searchButtonView,
                {
                    tag: 'div',
                    attributes: {
                        class: [ 'ck-result-grid' ]
                    },
                    children: this.items
                },
                this.saveButtonView,
                this.cancelButtonView,

            ]
        } );


// updateList method is like this:
    updateList( valuesArray ) {
        console.log(this.items);
        this.items = new Array();
        console.log(this.items);
        for (let i = 0; i < valuesArray.length && i < 20; i++) {
            const urlView = new TableSizeGridBoxView(i, valuesArray[i]);
            urlView.on('select-url', () => {
                this._selectedUrl = valuesArray[i];
            });
            this.items.push( urlView );
        }
        console.log(this.items);
        //do something here to force refresh or render the section
    }
```

I'm able to get

[image: this]

My expected result, after the search, is to get

[image: this]

and finally select the result.

Currently I can see the object correctly initialized and updated by doing console.log, but the view doesn't update... it stays blank as in the first image (that's why I think there must be something I should be able to put where I wrote `//do something here to force refresh or render the section`).

Furtermore I can tell that `TableSizeGridBoxView` is working properly because I'm able to display arbitrary values if I call the for loop in the initialization of the view.

Comment: This question has been [answered](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1681) on the official issue tracker of CKEditor 5.

Comment: @oleq I'm working on it now, but I'm not able to make it work yet... in the next few hours I hope I make their test to work, otherwise I'll ask them again and try to see what to do